# How to get rid of "%20" code in URLs (django)

Tags: html, django, django-templates

Am working with django 1.3 and doing some template inheritance. My `/static/` settings path seems to have problems once I leave the home page. Issue is, when I load home.html which inherits from base.html, the CSS and Image links work okay. But once I go to an extra URL (in this case vehicle.html), the css and image get lost with the error below:

**console error**

```
"GET /static/%20/static/images/logo_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 1771
"GET /static/%20/static/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1765
```

**view page source**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/ /static/css/default.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/ /static/css/default.css">
```

It looks like some space is appearing from somewhere. Also, from the vehilce.html file, the page source shows that its adding an extra `/static/` to the url plust the space. Where could I be going wrong? See below for my documents:

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'D:/dev/workspace/vehicle_request/vehicle_request/mvmanager/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^$', home_page),
                   (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
                   (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), #Not in use in my code yet
                   (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
                   (r'^vehicle/', vehicle),
                   (r'^driver/', driver),
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}/static/css/default.css">
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
<a href="http://localhost:8000" title="Home Page">
<img alt="logo2:" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/static/images/logo_2.jpg"
style="float:left; margin:5px" height="100"; border=none"></a><br><br>
<h1>Vehicle Request System <span class="version">(Version 0.1 beta)</span></h1>
</header>
<hr style="clear: left">
<hr>
</body>
</html>
```

**vehicle.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Vehicle Registration{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

Thanks.

**Edits**

**1.** I've changed the `stati` in `href="{{STATIC_URL}} /static/css/default.css">` to read `static` as that is how it is in my code. I must have backspaced by mistake while posting. Moving on however,

**2.** When I change `{{STATIC_url}} /Static` to `{{STATIC_URL}}/Static` ie. I remove the space between those two words -as suggested by @sarnold below-, `home.html` works as usual but `vehicle.html` still doesn't load the css and the image and it spews the error below in the console:

```
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 234, in path
raise SuspiciousOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '\static\images\logo_2.jpg' denied.
[10/Feb/2012 06:11:55] "GET /static//static/images/logo_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 1731

File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 234, in path
raise SuspiciousOperation("Attempted access to '%s' denied." % name)
SuspiciousOperation: Attempted access to '\static\css\default.css' denied.
[10/Feb/2012 06:23:29] "GET /static//static/images/logo_2.jpg HTTP/1.1" 500 1731
```

**3.** When I combine @sarnold and @cptphil suggestions, `vehicle.html` loads perfectly the css and the image. `home.html` however fails. See the changes to `base.html` below:

**base.html (edited to look like this)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/default.css">
<img alt="logo2:" src="{{STATIC_URL}}images/logo_2.jpg"
```

**home.html now doesnt' work! (viewing page source)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
<img alt="logo2:" src="images/logo_2.jpg"
```

**vehicle.html now works (viewing page source)**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/default.css">
<img alt="logo2:" src="/static/images/logo_2.jpg"
```

And this is how the **home.html** looks like in raw form

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}GEL: Vehicle Request System{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the template engine is doing what you are asking it to do.

```
href="{{STATIC_URL}} /stati/css/default.css"
```

correctly translates to

```
/static/ /stati/css/default.css
```

Try

```
href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/default.css"
```

in base.html if what you are after is

```
/static/css/default.css
```

Can't account for why home.html would work correctly though.

Comment: Hey, funny thing: If I do as you've suggested, `vehicle.html` loads the css and the image. BUT, `home.html` fails to load them! Interesting. What do you think is the issue? FYI, all the `html` docs are in one folder while the `image` and `css` are in their respective folders in the `static` folder.

Comment: That is interesting. Can you post your home.html code? Hard to know what could be the issue but that could help.

Comment: From the django docs: "If {{ STATIC_URL }} isn't working in your template, you're probably not using RequestContext when rendering the template." Is it possible that your home_page function's `render_to_response` is leaving out the `RequestContext`? link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#with-a-context-processor

Comment: Spot on! :-) in my `home_page` view, I didn't have the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` entry. I've just added it and it now works! Thanks a ton. However, correct me if am wrong: I thought you only require the `RequestContext` when you have a `POST` in your template? As such, I'd left it out while I had it in my `vehicle view`. Also as it is, I have the `{% csrf_token %}` in 'vehicle.html` as it has `POST` in it but I have left out the `{% csrf_token %}` in `home.html` as it doesn't have `POST`. Hope am doing it correctly.

Comment: Glad to hear it. RequestContext is just a shortcut for loading up and passing in variables to the template renderer, so if you use it anywhere you should use it everywhere - nothing to do with POST vs GET. From the docs: "As a brief refresher, context processors add variables into the contexts of every template. However, context processors require that you use RequestContext when rendering templates. This happens automatically if you're using a generic view, but in views written by hand you'll need to explicitly use RequestContext"

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you added the spaces manually to `base.html`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}} /stati/css/defau...
<img alt="logo2:" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/imag....
```

Take out the space before `/stati/css` and `/static/imag` and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: When I do as your suggestion, I get a different error as shown in `edit #2` in the original post above. So still not working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

space = %20. Be sure to omit space from your url...

```
like : <script src="{% static " js/dashboard/salesPieChart.js" %}"></script>
To: <script src="{% static "js/dashboard/salesPieChart.js" %}"></script>
```